# was trying for intent class to swap to new page in android but its not going to next page

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondPage.class);
               MainActivity.this.startActivities(i);

            }

        });


    }

    private void startActivities(Intent i) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `startActivities` method doesn't have body. To launch an Activity just call `startActivity(i)`

Comment: Why do you write the method `startActivities`? Does it have some code in?  Maybe @JorgeMendez 's comment is the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `MainActivity.this.startActivities(i);` to `startActivity(i);`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `startActivity(i);` instead of `MainActivity.this.startActivities(i);` like,

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondPage.class);
            startActivity(i); <---- here you need to modify like this

        }

    });
```